# Bugzilla or Mantis?

Tags: bug-tracking, project-planning, bugzilla, mantis

As the title says, I'm starting one project right now, and trying to layout the infrastructure for the project (SVN, Email, Bug tracking, Online Forums, etc...)

So, Bugzilla or Mantis?

Comment: Here is a [link to the mantis demo site](http://demo.mantisbt.org/my_view_page.php)

Comment: do you have to cover multiple projects with your system, or might that happen in the future?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130466/trac-vs-redmine-vs-jira-vs-fogbugz-for-one-man-shop

Answer (score 37):

I think you'll find that your team will like either Trac or Redmine more than Bugzilla or Mantis.   Both integrate nicely with Subversion.  Both include wiki, forums, project management features...

Quick overview:

**Trac**: Very widely used and loved, written in python, huge community, lots of "plugins".  A common complaint is that it doesn't support multiple projects out-of-the-box, but you can add a plugin to help with that.

**Redmine**: Written in RubyOnRails.  Like Trac, but more complete out of the box.  The authors of Redmine are trying to create a better Trac than Trac.

If you are interested in what others searching for bug trackers have written, comparing trackers to each other, I've put some links together here:
http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/2007/10/Links-to-other-comparisons-of-issue-trackers.aspx

If you on Windows, which I'm guessing you aren't, then also consider BugTracker.NET, an easy-to-use, very configurable [bug tracking](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) system in .NET/MS SQL Server.  (Disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: Can you add a link to the multi-proejct trac plugin?

Comment: As a noob that was recommended to use that, someone can answer if it is fully free and how to install it or if it is that kind cloud-like service. And also if it is that anyone-can-see thing or if I can protect what is mine...

Comment: Base your choice on what you love: ruby or python :)

Comment: With the question being "Bugzilla or Mantis?", "neither/another" is not really helpful.

Answer (score 24):

I like mantis. It's simple and it gets the job done.

Answer (score 24):

I've used Bugzilla and Mantis, but I prefer Mantis' simplicity. It's not as feature rich as Bugzilla but, I remember fighting with Bugzilla a lot more. Mantis is the kind of thing you can setup once then leave.

Answer (score 19):

Mantis definitely wins on usability grounds over Bugzilla.

In particular, it is just a lot faster to log bugs on Mantis. Time to log bugs is a blocker for some people - I've heard it used as an excuse for not logging them, fixing them and pretending there was never a bug to fix (symptomatic of deeper team problems).

It wasn't until a client (currently using Basecamp, bleah!) canned the idea of Mantis because it wasn't pretty enough that I realised some people (as noted above) think it is ugly.

Compared to Bugzilla or another system we tried implementing, some weird European thing, Mantis is gorgeous.

I know Mantis scales well - a friend used it for the production of the movie Happy Feet. He customised it by adding one extra field to provide another level of categorisation.

Answer (score 16):

Bugzilla is bigger, a larger community, more features, more power ... for that reason I've always prefered mantis ;) Mantis is as ugly as sin but for most projects it gives you what you need in a simple and intuative way.

If you have a large team, a big QA department and all the rest bugzillia may be a better fit. Small team that just needs to get stuff done - then mantis is probably better in my opinion.

The biggest feature missing from mantis (they may have added it since, this was a few years ago) is the reports feature so you can track progress with nice line and pie charts. However, I just wrote a simple PHP script to pull out the data and manually created them in Excel each week (only took 5 minutes or so). Not great but functionally sufficient for what we needed at the time.

However there online demos of both so I suggest you try them out and pick what suits you the best.

Comment: There is some reporting in newer mantis versions. I don't know how it compares, since I never managed to get bugzilla set up.

Comment: Accordingly to OhLoh.net [Mantis](http://www.ohloh.net/p/mantis) has 2,5x times the code of [Bugzilla](http://www.ohloh.net/p/bugzilla)

Answer (score 9):

**Mantis is great and very easy to setup**

I have been using it for about 3 years

It has the following problems.

There is a 2 Meg limit on the file size that you can store in issue. This becomes a problem when you want to include screen shots of the problem.

If two people update the issue at the same time - Someone will lose data

Comment: Are you sure that the 2MB limit is due to Mantis, since by default PHP has a 2MB limit on uploads, and this Mantis is written in PHP, this will therefore affect Mantis.  You can try changing the setting in PHP.ini for the upload size and that may solve the problems you are having with it.

Comment: yes, 2mb is just a PHP default. what's good about mantis - you can configure it to store files either directly in the DB or in the file system.

Comment: You can also choose an FTP option which would allow you to store files on a separate FTP server without requiring disk access to that location. The Mantis default file size limit out of the box is 5MB and the config files include a warning to check php.ini.

Answer (score 7):

I have used both and didn't like them at all, I prefer [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), thou if you really need to choose between those two I'd go for Bugzilla
The integration for TRAC with subversion is real good (have a look at [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) to see how the integration works )

Trac is also open source and its pretty simple to add new reports and stuff like that.

Answer (score 6):

Mantis is great and simple,
simplicity is important as my clients are non technical people.

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Redmine](http://redmine.org). It gives you repo access, trackers, forums, wiki, calendar - in one place.

Comment: It looks like a beta port of trac to ruby.  If you aren't a ruby partisan, it probably isn't the best.  I do like the integrated forums, but they look so bad I'd probably just install a copy of something else and be done.  Can't wait to see what its like in a year or so.

Answer (score 5):

I have extensively used Bugzilla (default for projects at work) but Mantis gets my vote for easy setup and use.

Answer (score 5):

I've heard good things about fogbugz but have yet to find an opportunity to use it.
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/

Answer (score 5):

I prefer mantis.  It performs nicely and is easily extend able either by the use of plugins or with by coding.

Answer (score 4):

Another vote for Trac -- dead simple to get going, nice web-based view into your repository, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Choosing the right bug tracker requires that you know who is going to use it (and how it is going to be used). I've used Bugzilla and Mantis and found Bugzilla better from a technical point of view but Mantis wins if some of your bug reporters are not programmers / not programmer minded. Its interface is less 'threatening' for a novice bugtracker user.

If you are going to have a private bugtracker you also need to consider the options it gives you to specify who is allowed to view/edit etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've used bugzilla for a while, but Redmine get my vote. easy setup, very very intuitive.